# Method for getting polymorphic relationship table name in Rails. Meta-programming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, metaprogramming, polymorphism

I want to test if a Polymorphic child belongs to parent.

```
@event.eventable_id == @current_user.id and @event.eventable_type == current_user.class.name
```

Now this is ugly and shouldn't be in the view like this.  But I'd like to do this check for every polymorphic object.  So I need a meta-programming way to figure out the naming scheme of the polymorphic relationship table.

```
phone to phonable
social to sociable
etc.
```

The method would look great like this.

```
if @event.belongs_to(current_user) #<NoMethodError: undefined method `belongs_to' for #<Event:
```

So I need a helper method to check the polymorphic relationship.  If I could get the name scheme of any polymorphic child like this

```
@event.polymorphic_relationship_table_name
```

I could then incorporate it in a meta-programming helper.  If there's already a solution built for this please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it!  This is the answer for getting the polymorphic relationship name scheme.

```
@event.class.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).first.name
=> :eventable # this is the ouput
```

And I can put any object instance in front of `.class.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).first.name`

The document that helped me the most on this was [Identifying Foreign Key Dependencies from ActiveRecord::Base Classes](http://viget.com/extend/identifying-foreign-key-dependencies-from-activerecordbase-classes) by Ryan Stenberg.

#### :-)

---

### Example Usage

First a helper method.

**app/helpers/application_helper.rb**

```
module ApplicationHelper    
  def child_and_parent?(obj, user)
    obj_id = Integer(eval "obj.#{obj.class.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).first.name}_id")
    obj_type = String(eval "obj.#{obj.class.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).first.name}_type")
    (user.id == obj_id) and (user.class.name == obj_type)
  end
end
```

And then use it in the view to remove features that don't belong to the current user.

**app/views/events/index.html.erb and app/views/events/show.html.erb**

```
<% if child_and_parent? @event, current_user %>
  <li><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_event_path(@event) %></li>
  <li><%= link_to 'Delete', @event, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Very cool! Thanks for following up ... this is good to have in the arsenal!

Comment: For anyone who's interested I've written a gem that allows you to access the parent object via a :parent method available on each object.  https://github.com/danielpclark/PolyBelongsTo gem 'poly_belongs_to'

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access all that you want and need from the instance itself:

```
@event.eventable.class.table_name
@event.eventable.class.to_s
```

And so on ... when I tested this in a local app that has a few polymorphic models, I was able to access the parent data from those methods with ease, which you could integrate into your app in a much cleaner way than what I wrote :). Hope it helps!

Comment: This only handles the Event object use case.  I'd have to manually enter in every use case for all the different polymorphic relationship types I have.  The **.eventable.** part needs to be figured out by some method or helper so I can write one method for all polymorphic types... DRY.